# How to protect GAE server-side calculation logic?

Tags: google-app-engine, client, client-server

Let's say I have 100 fields in the html form. When all fields are filled in, some score is calculated and shown to the user (let's say the score value is from 0 to 3000).

When user changes the value in any field, we show him value range (0-1000, 1001-2000, 2001-3000), no detail score. But once Submit button is pressed, exact score to be shown.

Now I need to protect the logic - so, users shouldn't be able to understand how each field affect the score. Also, users shouldn't be able to use some program to 'play' with the values and see how score is changed.

I am thinking about the following approach:

1. use sessions;
2. keep on the server side current value of the score;
3. when value in one field is changed, send request to the server with changed field name and new value;
4. on the server side validate when previous request was send, if time difference is too small, then reject request;
5. server replies with new range and saves new value;
6. when Submit is pressed, server replies with server value of the score (do not re-calculate it, take as is). Don't reply on this too often.

Are there any other (better) approaches?

Answer (score 1):

There is not a single solution to this. You may attempt make it hard for the user to hack it and to do so undetected and apply the coercive measures possible.

- use an "enabler" cookie (or set a session flag) when the user displays the form and check for this specific cookie or flag before you hand the response. Clear the enabler once a response has been provided and don't allow submissions for those who already submitted
- randomize field names and check at the server side if the fields have the proper random names
- use a cookie to check if the user already submitted the form (it's easy to defeat)
- check for user agent against popular HTTP libraries (and don't allow people to submit forms with them)
- monitor if the same IP makes lots of submissions - imprecise, but may indicate something fishy

Those are the first ideas that come to my mind. There will most likely be other insightful comments with others.

Answer (score 1):

For the client:

1. Send the data of the fields to the server and request for score calculations.
2. Put a constraint on your client so that it would wait for the server to finish replying the request sent on step #1 before sending a new one.
3. When the response from the server came back, check the values on the fields, if there is any change compared to the last time you were on step #1, re-do the step #1. If not, monitor the fields and go to step #1 when you detect any changes.

Now for the server:

1. When a request for recalculation come, calculate the new score, but then add an artificial latency before sending the result of the calculation back to the client. (e.g. sleep for 1000 ms before sending a reply back to the client)

With this strategy, you put a maximum rate for the user to 'play' with the values, without the need to have sessions and without the need to have a time-difference check for every incoming requests.

It would be even better if you send the result back to the client asynchronously, perhaps using the [Channel API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/overview.html), and put the sleep into a TaskQueue worker instead. That way, the app engine scheduler would not think that your app need to spawn lots of instances due to the high latency exhibited by your request handlers.

Comment: Thanks, Ibrahim. Could you please clarify how item 2 can be implemented?

Comment: I am assuming you are using AJAX to send your requests to the server? I would set up a `var hasReplyBeenReceived` flag that will be set to `false` when you send your request, and will be set to `true` once the callback method receives an answer. The function that send your requests will check this flag and do not execute the request if the flag is still false. You could also add a timer that will set this value to true after 20 seconds or so, just in case the server failed to send its reply.

Comment: Hmm, since I use jQuery, probably I can refer to ajaxStart/ajaxStop

Comment: I'm not familiar with jQuery, but that sounds to do the trick. :)