# How to implement delay in GAE replies?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, channel-api

Once I've got a message from the client, I don't want to reply immediately, I want to wait for a few seconds (**random** number of seconds). How can I do it? (I use Channel API, so such delay should be OK for the client)

Answer (score 1):

You can just make the thread sleep for a while:

```
import thread

...

   thread.sleep(some_number_of_milliseconds)
```

Comment: Is it better than using Task Queue? (@Moishe recommended to use Task Queue there - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9420887/604388)

Comment: Doesn't the sleep cause [performance/scalability issues](http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/general.html#activerequests) if the application has any serious number of users? (Especially when the sleep time is several seconds.)

Comment: Wouldn't that be counted as server time?

Answer (score 0):

The deferred built-in library would perform better than sleep for App Engine and is easier to setup than Task Queue.

```
[https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred][1]
```