# What should be used to store data in GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached, google-cloud-datastore

My web application will have ~150 fields and when value is changed in any field (at least one), I should save changed value. 
How should I store such values with GAE? Should I save them directly in datastore? Should I use memcache temporarily and then save all values at once in datastore? Or, some other approach should be followed?

Answer (score 3):

The datastore is your database. Memcache is to store data that's fetched from the datastore and kept temporarily in memory to avoid too many calls back to the database. You should first design your app around the datastore and then use memcache to improve performance.

Depending on your programming language of choice (java, python, go) there are many tools out there to help you map objects in your app to the datastore and to use memcache effectively.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should find out how you are going to use your data. Which queries are you planning to make? What is the size of your entities?

Datastore is very different from relational databases. That is It doesn't really matter how many properties are changed, because there is no way to update a property on its own. You can only save entity as a whole. I don't know about your use case, but there should probably be a better approach for structuring your data, than having ~150 properties for a single entity. What is your use case?

Also having too much properties for an entity may lead to index explosion, or to slow down datastore writes.

Comment: Thanks, Maxim. More details about my case can be found there - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232438/how-to-protect-gae-server-side-calculation-logic

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you split your entities in a root entity and a couple linked ones holding each some of the 150 attributes - this way, when you update one attribute, you only need to save one (or two, if the update reflects on the root entity) smaller entities to the datastore instead of a huge one.

Use memcache to prevent reads, not to store data that's going to the datastore. Memcache can be flushed and the data there can be destroyed before it hits permanent storage.

Going one step further, the grouping of attributes could reflect data that's updated together - say, if you always update *street* and *zipcode* together, it makes sense to keep them together in a single structure.